# How to get to Total Percentage of values that are based on other totals and values

Tags: sql, math

example:

Main Goal : 100%

```
Specific Goal 1 : 40%
Task 1 : 40%
Task 2 : 30%
Task 3 : 30%

Specific Goal 2 : 20%
Task 1 : 20%
Task 2 : 50%
Task 3 : 15%
Task 4 : 15%

Specific Goal 3 : 40%

Task 1 : 50%
Task 2 : 10%
Task 3 : 25%
Task 4 : 15%
```

we entry the rate for each task.

How to write SQL query to get the total of the specific goal total and main goal based on rate of all tasks.

just need the method to get that
thanks

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question for suggestions and examples of how you might improve your chances of getting the right answer. With the limited info you've provided, I'd be surprised if anyone could provide much help. We need more details on your tables, data, code you've tried and what the expected output should look like.

Comment: @D.Jhon . . . Please add sample data *as text tables* and show the results that you want.  It is quite unclear what your data looks like.